# How to create a file using imagepath from different storage locations

Tags: android, kotlin, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

By using GligarPicker ImagePicker got List of ImagePaths , each image is from different locations like

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20210219-WA0000.jpeg
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/Hangto/IMG-2034543533219-TQQ1.jpeg
```

creating files and storing it in app level folder using fileDescriptor and FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. sending these images to server using retrofit multipart.
To store these user selected images in app level folder i want to create files using above image paths.Here how to create files

Tried this :

```
  val uri = Uri.parse("file://" + imagesList[i].toString())
  val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? =
                        requireContext().contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r")
                    val fileDescriptor: FileDescriptor? = parcelFileDescriptor?.fileDescriptor
      val file = File(
                        requireContext().externalCacheDir?.path,
                        requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(uri!!)
                    )
                    file.mkdir()
                    file.createNewFile()
                    val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor)
                    val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                    inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
```

App is crashing at   val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file) as file
crash report:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.visilogix.smarttrax/cache: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
```

Here after creating file i tried to get file absolute path and it returns

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<packagename>/cache
```

based on logs i came to conclusion that filePath, which i'm referring is wrong , how to fix it.

Comment: `How to create file using above ImagePaths` Strange question. Those are files already. Please first tell what you want to do with them. (In your post on the right place before the code).

Comment: But before that.. Start your post with telling how your app obtained those paths as ... you were already told so.. image pickers will mostly not deliver such file system parhs. And start reacting on comments otherwise we cannot help you.